# How to add a prefix based routes in Luracast/Restler

Tags: php, restler

I'm using `Luracast/Restler` php framework. I know it have the privilege to use version based URLs in it using the `Defaults::$useUrlBasedVersioning` property and `$restler->setAPIVersion()` function. I have a requirement like instead of using the version based URL [Ex: `v1/resource`] I want to add prefix like api [Ex: `api/resource`]. I don't want to make this prefix change via server configuration.  I want to add this changes in the gateway file. As like I added v1 prefix in the first example.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like it's a related to this issue that I've opened at https://github.com/Luracast/Restler/issues/691.

The workaround that I use, is actually a hard-coded solution. In the `Restler.php` file, change the request parameters like this:

```php
$_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME'] = "/api/";
```